# Storage for chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, html5-filesystem

I am working on a chrome extension for managing sessions.
I would like to store some data related to sessions and this is what I have found out till now:

1) Local Storage: Looks good to me, but I am afraid I may have too much data, and there seems to be quota on the storage. Also, local storage is more of a long-term cache, not too much dependable.

2) SQLite: not sure how it works. Need more advice on this.

3) Chrome Filesystem API: Available only on apps, not extensions.

4) HTML5 Filesystem API: Works on a virtual file-system

Please advise on the possible options.

Comment: Has this been resolved for you? Did any of the answers answer your question? If so, would you mind accepting the most helpful answer as "accepted"? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the chrome.storage API? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Already checked, it was there that I saw the quota on data storage. However, there's one thing which I just noticed: permission for "unlimitedstorage". Does this work? I really need my data to be persistent.

Comment: @sg1993 You can always request `unlimitedStorage` permission. Hard quotas only apply to `sync` storage, `local` is unlimited with that permission.

Comment: @sg1993 And furthermore, _unless_ you request that permission, the same quota applies to all HTML5 storage.

Comment: @Xan thanks, just noticed that. I will definitely try that first.

Answer (score 1):

How about `IndexedDB`,
It's known for being great for client side apps, and has Unlimited space to store anything type of data you want.